# Advanced Computer/AI defeated by simple virus

Tags: story-identification

My fiance is looking for a story, can't remember if it was a movie or a TV episode or a book where an advanced computer/AI/robot army was defeated by a super old virus, because they hadn't thought to defend against something so old and primitive. I know this is not much to go on, but it's been bugging her for a few days now and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Independence Day!

Comment: This almost sounds like *War of the Worlds*, but those were aliens, not AI

Comment: @Odin1806 That sounds right, I am checking with her just to he sure. I also can't believe I didn't think of that one, I love that movie... Post that answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Machavity Yeah, I confirmed it wasn't that one.

Comment: @Machavity And that was aliens, not AI/Computers.

Comment: @JMac Which is what I said?

Comment: @Machavity  ... I actually don't know what the heck I read.  I thought I even re-read it for that.  Had a weird brain fart I guess.

Comment: Ultron once got taken out that way in the comics?